# cannot navigate next page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Does anyone know why my navigation page isnt working after I click the icon Parking which will lead me to other pages which will display an appbar.

[image: coding for navigate to parking screen]

[image: Inside parking_screen.dart, I called the app_bar_parking function]

[image: Details for my appbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have this kind of code in your ParkingScreen.dart file

```
 class ParkingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParkingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Parking Screen')),
      body: SafeArea(child: Column()),
    );
  }
}
```

This happens because you are trying to navigate between two different app roots

Answer (score 4):

I can not test your code but I think this happens because you are trying to navigate between two different app roots. Try removing the **MaterialApp** widget from your "parkingscreen.dart" file. Keep only the **Scaffold** widget since it contains all material components for you to work. Let me know if it works!

Comment: is it much better if Im using return scaffold rather than return materialapp?

Comment: Yes, you need only one MaterialApp and that should be the root of your application. To have access to all material widgets and components use only scaffold. :)